# Apollo GraphQL map list entities from multiple sources

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

There is an entity list that has data from two sources. Dimensions like id, name, label, ... and metrics like games played, wins and so on.
Those are stored in different endpoints. I want to query filtered data from one source and having ids ask for data from another source at once, not by one entity by one of all entities? A primary set of the list can be queried from both or resources depending on sort options.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question entirely, at least not the last part... But can't you do it in the resolver? Just have it return the entire object, containing dimensions and metrics and let graphql handle the rest from there..

Comment: Well, yes, you can, but it means that for each entity it will request REST resource to get data. For example, if I have a list of 20 items, it will make 20 calls to the resource. I would like to do it in one call passing a list of IDs and map it resolver.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you need, but you can have a look. Like I said, not everything about what you're asking is clear.
https://launchpad.graphql.com/kqm3pkx557

Comment: yes, this solution should solve my problem. I will try it tomorrow. If you would add it as an answer I would check it as answered

Comment: Good to hear! Wrote an answer with it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a query that accepts one or a list of arguments. The resolver would make the two requests and when the responses come back, merge them and return the merged list.

Check out [this](https://launchpad.graphql.com/kqm3pkx557) launchpad for an example of what I'm saying.